# Spring does not convert JSON array to list in my DTO

Tags: java, json, spring, controller, dto

Does Spring allow to convert list of elements from json to `List<Long>` in my dto? What I'm doing wrong? Hemp mw please to solve this problem.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWezk.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIG4x.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/3C4gu.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/evXIY.png

I tried everything just can't find the problem.

Comment: Please dont use images. Provide the code as part of the question
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the request body, you should not use `kPartIds` instead use `kpartIds`. When Lombok generates the get/set method it will change the first character to uppercase. Now the second character is also uppercase. So while converting JSON to object it will find both as lower character objects.

```
{
    "title": "Test",
    "kpackIds": [5, 10]
}
```

Also as @user2131323 mentioned. Use actual code snippets instead of images.

Comment: Thanks, it helped! That's my first post, so next time I will definitely use code instead of img)